# draw on image not fit original one perfectly

Tags: tikz-pgf

Say I draw a red image with below code, generate input.pdf:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1pt,y=1pt,line width = 1pt,red]
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (50,50);
    \draw (25,25) circle (25);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Then include input.pdf and draw the same thing on this image (draw with black):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1pt,y=1pt,line width = 1pt]
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0,outer sep=0] at (0,0) {\includegraphics{input.pdf}};
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (50,50);
    \draw (25,25) circle (25);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But the black line not over red line perfectly,see below zoomed parts:

[image]

What's wrong with my draw on image code?

Comment: Well, seems like you did not take into account the line width. Try putting the image at (-\pgflinewidth/2,-\pgflinewidth/2) to take this into account.

Comment: I think the problem is the `draw`. Replace it by `\fill[yellow]` and `\fill[green]` for exmple.

Comment: @marmot is right. put your node at `(-0.5,-0.5)` (half line width offset) and it lines up right. Your image is actually 51pt × 51pt but your code assumes it is 50pt × 50pt.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OK, I just tried what I thought should work, and surprisingly it does. That is.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1pt,y=1pt,line width = 1pt]
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0,outer sep=0] at (-\pgflinewidth/2,-\pgflinewidth/2) {\includegraphics{input.pdf}};
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (50,50);
    \draw (25,25) circle (25);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

as expected. Why? You put the node with anchor `south west`, and, as pointed out
by David Purton, your image is wider (and taller) by the line width (since it is wider and taller by half the line width in each direction). And why is this? You draw a path through the specified coordinates, and the line width gets added to this. I know that the explanation is very clumsy, it would be much easier in marmot language, but I am not sure how to type this, so as a compromise I add a figure. ;-)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to @marmot's solution is to put the image at (25,25) to line up with your circle and anchor it at it's centre:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1pt,y=1pt,line width = 1pt]
    \node[inner sep=0,outer sep=0] at (25,25) {\includegraphics{input.pdf}};
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (50,50);
    \draw (25,25) circle (25);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```